# Greenfoot: java.lang.ClassCastException: Obstacle cannot be cast to BallProjectile

Tags: java, greenfoot

Alright, so I get this error when I try to make it so that when BallProjectile collides with an obstacle, the ball stops and makes a new one.

```
// Checks if the ball is colliding with an obstace, then stops it if it is

BallProjectile obstacleCollision = (BallProjectile) getOneIntersectingObject(Obstacle.class);
        if (obstacleCollision != null)
        {
            xSpeed = 0;
            ySpeed = 0;
            myWorld.addObject(new BallProjectile(), 50, 559);
            return;
        }
```

How do I stop this error?  Note that obstacle is just that, a circle created to get in the way of the ball.

Comment: add some debug statements into your code to verify that the correct code is being called when expected

Comment: So I think the problem is that getSpeedValue and getAngleValue are broken, not athing in BallProjectile, but I've been doing trial and error for hours and nothing has worked

Comment: I guess it would be interesting to see what the `getOneIntersectingObject()` method returns.

Comment: This set of comments was from a while ago, and it unrelated to the question at hand, I'm just not sure how to delete this comment chain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only place where you're doing a cast in the code provided is:

```
BallProjectile obstacleCollision = (BallProjectile) getOneIntersectingObject(Obstacle.class);
```

So I think it's where your problem is. Seems like the return of this method cannot be cast as `BallProjectile`

**EDIT:**

To verify your collision you could do either:

```
Obstacle obstacleCollision = (Obstacle) getOneIntersectingObject(Obstacle.class);
if(obstacleCollision != null) {
   //do your things here
}
```

**OR**

```
Actor obstacleCollision = getOneIntersectingObject(Obstacle.class);
if(obstacleCollision != null) {
   //do your things here
}
```

Both approaches should work the same way

Comment: If that's the case how do I make it detect that it's colliding with the obstacle and stop the ball?

Comment: Just a quick note, I am very new to Greenfoot.  Anyway, If I remove the casting, I get an incompatible types error and Greenfoot highlights Obstacle.class

Comment: The java API says:   getOneIntersectingObject

protected Actor getOneIntersectingObject(java.lang.Class cls)

    Return an object that intersects this object. This takes the graphical extent of objects into consideration.

    Parameters:
        cls - Class of objects to look for (passing 'null' will find all objects).